# Why am I not able to see the numbers of views for any question?

Tags: support

I don't know from how long it was happening, but from a last couple of days I noticed that I am not able to see the number of views for any question anymore.
Was it removed? or Only I face the issue? I tried it on different devices and same problem.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xzrgKKJ.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the view count in the right sidebar? It was moved; it is now just below the question title.

Comment: Thanks. But I never got any announcement about this change.

Comment: I'm sure it's been like that for months. I don't know why you're only just noticing it, but the apparent lack of announcement would be because this change happened ages ago.

Comment: @InQusitive The "Asked" date, "Active" date, and "Viewed" count were moved from the sidebar to just under the question title on 2019-07-25. I don't believe there was an actual announcement, but there were definitely [various meta questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331349/271271) about it, when it happened. On Stack Overflow Meta, the issue was overshadowed by the removal of the Hot Meta Posts from the sidebar, which had happened a couple days earlier. If you want, the userscript [Sidebar Question Stats](https://stackapps.com/q/8382/29529) will move those items back to the sidebar.